Eigenvalues of Composition of Hadamard Operations of Low Rank Matrices
I am interested in the eigenvalues of $$ee^T \oslash (aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T )^{\odot \frac{1}{2}},$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $e$ is the vector with all entries equal to one.
Can we write them explicitly in terms of $a$ or the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $$aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T?$$
In the setting of interest, the entries of $a$ are the same order, positive, and less than 1.
To be clear, the (i,j)  entry is given by $$\frac{1}{(a_i a_j - a_i^2 a_j^2)^{1/2}}.$$
One can calculate the eigenvalues of $$aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T$$ explicitly in terms of $\langle a, a^{\odot 2} \rangle,$ $\Vert a \Vert$, and $\Vert a^{\odot 2} \Vert$ using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112186/eigenvalues-of-a-sum-of-rank-one-matrices.
Moreover, we have
$$ee^T \oslash (aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T ) = ee^T \oslash aa^T + ee^T \oslash (ee^T - aa^T),$$
which is the Hadamard square of the thing whose eigenvalues we want.
This is the sum of a Hermitian rank one matrix $$ee^T \oslash aa^T$$ and a Hermitian rank two matrix (the second term), though its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not immediately obvious to me.
I am not able to combine these facts in any meaningful way, but I suspect from simulations that the eigenvalues of interest decay rapidly, i.e., $$\lambda_1 (ee^T \oslash (aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T )^{\odot \frac{1}{2}})$$ is much greater than $$\lambda_2 (ee^T \oslash (aa^T - a^{\odot2}(a^{\odot2})^T )^{\odot \frac{1}{2}}),$$ etc...assuming the eigenvalues are in descending order.

Cross posted without cross posting notice.
